# Convert array of functions to array of strings

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array of functions:

```js
let myArray = [foo, bar, baz];
```

and i want to convert that to an array of strings with the function names:

```js
let myArrayAsStrings = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
```

How can I do that?

I have tried doing

```js
myArray.map(fn => fn.name)
```

however my babel config is i think mangling the function names, so it cannot be guaranteed that the name will be the same.

Wondering if there's some kind of 'convert var name to string' method I don't know about?

Comment: myArrayAsStrings = myArray.join(); try this one

Comment: @Vanns35 that stringifies it - which makes a string out of the entire function and its body. Have seen that before, and then people use regex / substr to find the name, but it feels a bit yuck.

Answer (score 1):

It’s unclear if `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` are normal functions (`function foo() {}`), unnamed functions (`var foo = funtion () {}`), or arrow functions (which can be only anonymous). `fn.name` will work only for the first case, the other two won’t have a name.

Theoretically, this could be a workaround:

```js
var myArrayAsStrings = Object.keys({ foo, bar, baz });
```

This will first store each function as a property and then we can extract properties names from the object as an array of keys. The downside of this solution is that the order either cannot be guaranteed.

However, if there is some sort of uglification then the original names from the code will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine, just add `toString()` at the end and push it into an array

```js
var foo = function() {
    console.log("Foo");
  };
  var bar = function() {
    console.log("bar");
  };
  var baz = function() {
    console.log("baz");
  };
  let myArray = [foo, bar, baz];
  let myArrayAsStrings = [];
  myArray.map(fn => myArrayAsStrings.push(fn.name.toString()));
  console.log(myArrayAsStrings);
```

Comment: yep that's what i've tried, but the `.name` property cannot be guaranteed as Babel is uglifying the funciton names

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer is assuming there's an array of vars (as the title says), not an array of functions:

A one line solutuion :

```
myArray.toString().split(",")
```

Comment: the title has a typo in it , `myArray`  is an array of functions not an array of variables